# Django: Should I use LocMemCache caching?

Tags: python, django

I am using this [QR code generator](https://github.com/dprog-philippe-docourt/django-qr-code#qr_url_from_text). There is a specific part in the documentation about caching. I read that `LocMemCache` should not be used in production. Is that also the case for these QR codes? Is there a caching that you can recommend instead, or is that approach fine at the beginning with a smaller page?

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    },
    'qr-code': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'qr-code-cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 3600
    }
}

QR_CODE_CACHE_ALIAS = 'qr-code'
```

Answer (score 4):

The LocMemCache backend just uses an object that is not shared across processes so it will use much memory when run in a production setting with more than one worker.

It can be sufficient if you're using it just for a small app but keep in mind that the server's memory needs to be big enough to contain the cached values. If there's not enough memory on your small VM then the server will not be able to handle responses properly.